# Form of an element of a normal subgroup of $A_n$

Tags: permutations

I want to show that $A_n$ is simple for $n\geq 5$.

For $n=5$ I have used the following criterion

Let $H$ be a normal subgroup of $A_5$ then $H$ can contain any one of the following

$a.$ a $5$ cycle of the form $(a,b,c,d,e)$

$b.$ a $3$ cycle of the form $(a,b,c)$

and $c.$ product of two disjoint $2$ cycles $(a,b)(c,d)$

in all the cases I am able to show that a $3$ cycle is in $H$ and thus $H=A_5$

Now I  want to argue in the general case .How should I split the cases here; because suppose $H$ is a  normal subgroup of $A_n;n>5$ then how will I know what  form an element of $H$ will have .Please help I am totally confused

Comment: See Theorems 2, 3, and 4 in https://rutherglen.science.mq.edu.au/ccooper/Groups/CHAP11%20Soluble%20Groups.pdf

Comment: Have you had a chance to follow-up on that link?

Comment: yes sir,it has helped me a lot @GerryMyerson

Comment: Good! Maybe when you're ready, you can summarize, and post an answer to your question.

Comment: Sir I have to appear in an interview regarding group theory .Can u please help which topics should I highlight more ;I cant figure out as the topic is so dense.@GerryMyerson

Comment: You had better speak to whomever it is who is going to interview you. I don't see how I could possibly advise you, when I know nothing about this interview.